# Causing Word 2010 to break to mid-page

Tags: microsoft-word-2010

I've got a Word 2010 document with a couple of custom styles that are made to look like sub-headings. Ideally I want them to only appear at either the top of a page or at the centre of a page, however aligning them manually to the centre of the page isn't a very attractive option and is prone to errors.

Is there a way to configure a style so it can only appear at certain positions of a page, and would break to the next available position where appropriate?

I'm guessing not, so my next question would be is it possible to add a new type of break similar to a page break that can break to a specific position (in my case, the vertical centre) of a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about vertical centering, but you can configure a style to force a page-break prior, if that's what you're looking for.

- Open the Modify Style dialog
- Format (button)
- Paragraph...
- "Line and Page Breaks" (tab)
- "Page break before" (checkbox; under Pagination)

Note: I am using Word 2007, but it should be similar on 2010.

Comment: Add to that a ridiculously large **Spacing Before** (roughly 300 pt)and you can essentially center the style mid-page, assuming all pages are the same height.